# How to Disable Pretty String for Struct Field

Tags: serialization, rust, pretty-print, serde

I am trying to find a way to disable `string-prettify` for `struct` fields

**My `struct`:**

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
pub struct Span {
    pub start: (i32, i32),  // ( Line, Column)
    pub end: (i32, i32),  // ( Line, Column)
}
```

**Output:** ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3cf40971f20db061f727439e776cf25))

```json
"span": {
    "start": [
        12,
        12
    ],
    "end": [
        12,
        12
    ]
}

// to something like this

"span": {
    "start": [12,12],
    "end": [12,12]
}
```

- Is there any `Field attributes` or custom method to do this?

I commonly need to analyze `json` files containing these `Span`.

Comment: This is awkward to do with serde-json. One hack would be to copy the implementation of [`PrettyFormatter`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/ser/struct.PrettyFormatter.html) and remove the methods related to arrays from the `Formatter` implementation, but this would affect _all_ arrays in the output, not only these specific ones.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way, I think. Because I neither override the `serialize_tuple` implementation nor switch the `PrettyFormatter` to custom. By the way, thanks for you reply.